# ¿Base de datos en R?

Tags: r, rodbc

Saludos, tengo problemas con la inserción de nuevos registros a una Base de Datos.

Uso la libreria `RODBC` para conectarme a la base de datos desde R, hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando deseo agregar un registro que tengo almacenado en un data frame como:

```
datos<- data.frame(nombre="juan",edad=22)
sqlSave(canal,tablename="alumnos",datos,append=TRUE)
```

Me sale error, ¿qué puedo hacer? ¿tienen alguna sugerencia? Espero su respuesta. Muchas gracias.

**Actualización:**

Mi código es simple:

```
library(RODBC) 
canal <- odbcConnect("PrMYSQL",uid = "root") 
datos<-data.frame(nombre='alberto', edad=31,sexo= 'masculino') 
guardar<- sqlQuery(canal,"INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre,edad,sexo) VALUES (",paste(datos[1,]),")")
```

Al ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error in if (errors) return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel)) else
return(invisible(stat)) : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: trata de indicar en la pregunta cuál es el error que te aparece

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español! Para hacer más sencillo que recibas una respuesta adecuada, por favor incluye dentro de tu pregunta el código que estás ejecutando y el error que te reporta R. Te recomiendo que visites nuestro centro de ayuda y leas ["¿Cómo preguntar?"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece?

Comment: Saludos mi codigo es simple: library(RODBC) canal <- odbcConnect("PrMYSQL",uid = "root") datos<-data.frame(nombre='alberto', edad=31,sexo= 'masculino') guardar<- sqlQuery(canal,"INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre,edad,sexo) VALUES (",paste(datos[1,]),")")

al ejecutar me sale el sgte error:

Error in if (errors) return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel)) else return(invisible(stat)) : argument is not interpretable as logical

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: El problema parece ser que las cadenas de texto *no* están encerradas entre comillas. Prueba con esto: `datos <- data.frame(nombre="'alberto'", edad=31, sexo="'masculino'")`

Comment: Por otro lado, tu código es terriblemente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Te recomiendo aprendas a usar consultas parametrizadas. [Este enlace](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html) contiene instrucciones para utilizar consultas parametrizadas (está en inglés... si encuentro un recurso en español, lo publicaré también como comentario)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y con tus consejos ya solucione el problema, lo que intento hacer es un aplicativo en shiny que ingresa cada variable de un usuario y este registro sea guardado en una base de datos que ya tengo, el codigo que use como ejemplo fue:

Comment: datos1<- data.frame(codigo=8,nombre='JUAN alberto', edad=23,sexo= 'masculino')

Comment: sqlQuery(canal, paste0("INSERT INTO alumnos (codigo,nombre,edad,sexo) 
                        VALUES ( '",datos1$codigo,"',
                                 '",datos1$nombre,"',
                                 '",datos1$edad,"',
                                 '",datos1$sexo,"' )"
                       )
         )

Answer (score 3):

Veo que modificaste tus datos, este sería el correcto formato:

```
canal <- odbcConnect("PrMYSQL",uid = "root") 
datos<-data.frame(codigo=1, nombre='alberto', edad=31,sexo= 'masculino') 
guardar<-sqlQuery(canal, paste0("INSERT INTO alumnos (codigo,nombre,edad,sexo) VALUES ( '",datos$codigo,"', '",datos$nombre,"', '",datos$edad,"', '",datos$sexo,"' )" ) )
```

este error:

```
Error in if (errors) return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel)) else
return(invisible(stat)) : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

se genera principalmente por el uso incorrecto de `paste` o `paste0`

Answer (score 1):

Concuerdo con Elenasys en que el error esta en el **paste()**, pero es posible usar el renglón para la consulta. Sin embargo tienes dos problemas, al extraer de un **data.frame** creado por **as.data.frame**, se generan factores y estos se convierten a número al usar **paste**, por otro lado esta el problema de concatenar columnas.
Con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
datos<-data.frame(nombre='alberto', edad=31,sexo= 'masculino')
```

Puedes concatenar tu cadena con **do.call()**

```
 do.call(paste, c(datos,sep=","))
 [1] "alberto\",\"31\",\"masculino"
```

Las primeras y las ultimas comillas no cuentan porque son parte de la salida de R y solo cuentan las que están precedidas por **\**

Quedando entonces como:

```
canal <- odbcConnect("PrMYSQL",uid = "root") 
datos<-data.frame(codigo=1, nombre='alberto', edad=31,
                  sexo= 'masculino') 
guardar<-sqlQuery(canal, paste0('INSERT INTO alumnos
                  (codigo,nombre,edad,sexo) VALUES 
                  ("', do.call(paste, c(datos[1,],sep='","')),'")')
```

Espero esto pueda servirte.